# Newly appened div class change using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change class of newly appended div every time. can I? How?

```
HTML:    
<form class="form_num">
    Name:<input type="text" class="name_first"/>
</form>
<span class="new_form"></span>
<button type="submit" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").click(function(){
       $(".form_num").clone().appendTo(".new_form").attr("class","form_num2");
       });
   });
```

Comment: did you googled : `addClass()`, `removeClass()`, `toggleClass()` jQuery helpers?

Comment: I need like..first time on click, class is form_num2, then form_num3, then form_num4.................

Comment: So you need to set a integer variable to be incremented on each click and concatenated to `form_num` string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this very easily like shown below in the demo:-

```js
var n = 1;
$("#submit").click(function() {
     $(".form_num").clone().appendTo(".new_form").attr("class", "form_num" + ++n)
     
     // This is not needed as clone method returns the newly added form element
     //$('.new_form').find(".form_num").attr("class", "form_num" + ++n);  
           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form_num">
  Name:
  <input type="text" class="name_first" />
</form>
<span class="new_form"></span>
<button type="submit" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using `jQuery.find()` here? `appendTo(".new_form")` will normally return the needed jQuery and attr() will be chained. am I right? thanks palash

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had forgotten that `clone()` return the new element and we can continue any operation on that element using the chaining. +1

Answer (score 0):

this normally should work:

```
var i = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").click(function(){
      $(".form_num").clone().appendTo(".new_form").attr("class","form_num"+i);
      i++;
       });
   });
```

**jsfidlle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/4smhx797/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this -

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     //initialize counter
     var incrementer = 0;
     $("#submit").click(function() {
         $(".form_num").clone().appendTo(".new_form").attr("class", "form_num" + incrementer );
         incrementer++;
     });
 });
```